# On hover, highlight div and all other divs with the same text

Tags: jquery, css, text, hover, matching

I can't get my head around this! Help please!

What I'm trying to do is when I hover over a div class I want the background of that div to change BUT I also want all other divs with that class to change background colour IF they have the same text value.

For example:

[image: hover multiple with same text]

John is mentioned 3 times and Lewis is mentioned twice. All others are there only once. Hovering over John will highlight the hovered div along with all other divs with the same text. Then, the highlight should be removed when no longer hovered.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.users > .user').hover(function() {
        var current = $(this);
        $('.users > .user').each(function() {
            if (!$(this).is(":contains('" + current.text() + "')")) {
                $(this).closest('.users > .user').addClass('bg2');                  
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```css
* {padding:0;margin:0;box-sizing:border-box;}
ul {
list-style-type:none;
width:150px;
}
li {
height:40px;
background-color:#FFF5D7;
margin-bottom:10px;
line-height:38px;
text-align:center;
font-family:arial;
font-weight:bold;
border:2px solid #999;
}

.bg2 {background-color:#4DA6FF;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="users">
    <li class="user">John</li>
    <li class="user">Peter</li>
    <li class="user">John</li>
    <li class="user">Lewis</li>
    <li class="user">Graham</li>
    <li class="user">Shaun</li>
    <li class="user">John</li>
    <li class="user">Lewis</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: How about you start with a bit of basic research then? https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript%20hover%20effect%20for%20all%20elements%20with%20same%20class%20site:stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this.

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.users > .user').mouseenter(function () {
      var current = $(this);
      $('.users > .user').each(function () {
        // Contains Matches For Text Everywhere In Word
        // if ($(this).is(":contains('" + current.text() + "')")) {
        // This way you match full text
        // Using Trim To Also Make Sure You Have No Empty Spaces
        if ($(this).text().trim() === current.text().trim()) {
          $(this).closest('.users > .user').addClass('bg2');
        }
      });
    });
    $('.users > .user').mouseleave(function () {
      $('.users > .user').removeClass("bg2");
    });
  });
```

But as others have said, you might want to do some research first before asking question that were probably answered before.

Comment: Hi Dragos, I appreciate your help. It has worked very well but the only issue I have now is that if I add another person called "John-Smith" to the list, hovering over "John" will also highlight the div that contains John-Smith. I was hoping for exact matching text.
I have looked around for solutions without success, therefore I am here. Thanks.

Comment: @making5 i have edited the answer, make sure to mark as answered if this suits your needs, so other can find this useful too.

Comment: Thanks. Worked perfectly.